# Get rid of color gradient for column headers in Google Visualization table

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-visualization

When I modify the column header colors using the event listener method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483084/change-color-of-specific-column-header), I get a default gradient. The snippet example linked also is also showing the default gradient in the second column. How would I go about getting rid of the gradient when the color is generated by the event listener?

Comment: I think this link will help you https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#labeling-columns

Comment: @vignesh Are you referring to the annotations.boxStyle section under the Configuration options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `background` instead of `backgroundColor`.

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
    data.addRows([
      ['Shoes', 10700],
      ['Sports', -15400],
      ['Toys', 12500],
      ['Electronics', -2100],
      ['Food', 22600],
      ['Art', 1100],
      ['Web', 9999]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('table_div');
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
      container.getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].cells[1].style.background = 'magenta';
    });

    table.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true
    });
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks again @WhiteHat! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@WhiteHat or you can disable the stupid `background-image`

```
.google-visualization-table .gradient {
    background-image: none;
}
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
    data.addRows([
      ['Shoes', 10700],
      ['Sports', -15400],
      ['Toys', 12500],
      ['Electronics', -2100],
      ['Food', 22600],
      ['Art', 1100],
      ['Web', 9999]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('table_div');
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);

    table.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true
    });
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```css
.google-visualization-table .gradient {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: "#eee";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```