# Change google visualization table date format

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

`How to change the date format in google visualization table?` I have data feed with `01-08-2016`. But when I sort the table It's not sorting correctly. Please check the two images below. 
[image]

I used this code but not working.

```
var monthYearFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ 
         pattern: "dd-MM-yyy" 
    }); 
    monthYearFormatter.format(data, 0);
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use `DateFormat`, the column must be of type `'date'`

if you're building the `DataTable` from an array,
you can provide the column type along with the label,
by using object notation
`{label: 'Date', type: 'date'}`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [{label: 'Date', type: 'date'}],
      [new Date('07/07/2016')],
      [new Date('07/08/2016')],
      [new Date('07/09/2016')],
      [new Date('07/10/2016')],
      [new Date('07/11/2016')],
      [new Date('07/12/2016')],
      [new Date('07/13/2016')],
      [new Date('08/01/2016')]
    ]);

    var monthYearFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
      pattern: "dd-MM-yyy"
    });
    monthYearFormatter.format(data, 0);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true,
      sortAscending: true,
      sortColumn: 0
    });
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But my date format is "01-08-2016" . I used data.addColumn('date', 'Date'); and data.setCell(parseInt([i]),0,new Date((values[i]['Date']))); But dates not displaying properly. Only few dates can visible other columns display as NaN-NaN-NaN.

Comment: I solved the issue of converting date. Your solution works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know to add a clickable icon when mouse hover the rows of google table  when there is a "google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() "? Normally it displays arrow icon which isn't giving a idea to the user that this is clickable.

Comment: sure, do you have another question? Table charts produce a normal set of html table elements, easily modified when the `'ready'` event fires -- [here is a brief example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38160789/5090771), which modifies the background of the header cells...

Comment: Yes I have. Could you please look this one :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736519/wrap-each-row-by-link-google-visualization-table