# wrap each row by link google visualization table

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I have a pop windows for every table row once they selected by user from

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {}
```

But default google visualization table rows not display as clickable.

I want them to display as clickable to users. So I added this code with no luck.

```
var container = document.getElementById(divName);
var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);
table.draw(data, options);
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    container.getElementsByTagName('TR')[0].html = '<a href="#" />';
    console.log("table ready");
});
```

Even console not print anything. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want the cursor to change to a hand when the user hovers the row
you can use css on the chart `div`

```
#chart_div tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

you could also use the chart's `cssClassNames` option and assign the css that way
only problem there is you lose the chart's default css,
so have to supply more than just `cursor`

if you want a 'hyperlink' to show, you can change the text of the first cell
but you cannot wrap entire rows in an anchor tag `<a>`

see following working snippet, which incorporates both...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', '2015', '2016'],
      ['Jan', 10, 15],
      ['Feb', 12, 18],
      ['Mar', 14, 21],
      ['Apr', 16, 24]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var tableRows = container.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows;
      // change first cell to link
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(tableRows, function(row) {
        row.cells[0].innerHTML = '<a href="#">' + row.cells[0].innerHTML + '</a>';
      });
    });

    chart.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true
    });
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```css
#chart_div tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```